# Ways to connect two devices to each other

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I want to build an app but first I need to know about all ways that are possible to make a connection with two android devices. Over 3G, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi and etc, where can I get a list of this? (If it exists)

To be more clear, I want the better way to find an X device with my Y device and trade some information between them. It`s important to considerate that two devices need to be close each other.
Like the feature of change Friend Codes with friends on 3DS via LOCAL, got it?

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks already.

Comment: Did you at least read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/index.html

Comment: Nice! I`ll read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to establish a local connection, the following ways can be used.

1. Internet (Wifi, 4g, etc.). A webserver should be running and establish a secure connection between the 2 devices.
2. Bluetooth - An app can be written to establish a local connection to a friend who is running the same app.
3. NFC - An app can be written to establish a local connection to a friend who is running the same app.